# Is there any way to check the kills on a pet?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

On my dwarf citizens, I can check their kill list by selecting them with <kbd>v</kbd>, opening their status screen with <kbd>z</kbd>, and pressing <kbd>k</kbd>. Is there any way to view this screen for pets? I have a turret which has earned quite a name for itself, and I'd like to see what it has killed.

Comment: a turret? and i havent noticed anything myself would be nice to know.

Comment: @Paralytic - It's part of the Masterwork mod. I'd definitely recommend checking it out if you like DF. It adds a lot of cool stuff while simultaneously helping with [dwarven relativity](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2012:Physics#Special_Relativity).

Comment: Is it a vermin (held by owner) or a creature (follows owner)?

Comment: @kotekzot - It's a creature. Not actually available as a pet, but it is placed by pasturing it like any other creature.

Comment: You should be able to find it in Legends then.

Comment: @kotekzot - I'll keep that in mind, but I'm looking for a way to see it in fortress mode.

Comment: Most likely not without going through DFHack/DFusion scripting. Can you upload the save game somewhere to try it out with your data?

Comment: @MartinSojka - My internet connection isn't all that great here, but when I get home I'll upload a copy of it.

Comment: @MartinSojka - [Here it is](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/18771657/region4.7z). I know how badly you want to see my awesome fortress :P
This is for Masterwork 1.9.5. I don't think I've modified the raws enough that it would be incompatible.

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot the raws are included in the save.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Vanilla game

As soon as the pet gains a name, it becomes a historical figure. This means it *does* show up in the "Legends" mode, and you can copy your save game folder, load it, abandon the fort then start a game in "Legends" mode with this folder to check.

[image]

You probably want to write down the name of the pet in question, since you can only search by name, not by race.

### Using mods

In fortress mode, you need an extended tool like [DFHack](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=91166.0), which allows you to write Lua scripts interfacing the internal data of the game while it's running. For example, this little script for DFHack will show you all notable kills of the selected unit.

```
-- Show the kills of the unit under cursor

local gui = require 'gui'
local dlg = require 'gui.dialogs'
local figures = df.global.world.history.figures
local events = df.global.world.history.events
local creatures = df.global.world.raws.creatures.all

local unit = dfhack.gui.getSelectedUnit(true)

if unit then
    local kills = {}
    if unit.hist_figure_id > 0 then
        local f = figures[unit.hist_figure_id]
        if f.info.kills then
            for _,e in ipairs(f.info.kills.events) do
                -- events[e] is of type history_event_hist_figure_diedst
                local ev = events[e]
                local victim = figures[ev.victim]
                local name = dfhack.TranslateName(victim.name)
                local race = (creatures[victim.race]).caste[victim.caste].caste_name[0]

                table.insert(kills, name .. " (" .. race .. ") in year " .. ev.year)
            end
            -- Show the kills
            dlg.showListPrompt(
                '--- Notable kills ---',
                nil, COLOR_WHITE,
                kills,
                nil, nil, 70
            )
        else
            dlg.showMessage(nil, "This peaceful soul didn't kill anyone. Yet.")
        end
    end
end
```

Save if as `showkills.lua` or similar in the `hack\scripts\` directory and you'll be able to use it by either calling the script name (`showkills`) on the DFHack prompt, or binding it to a key combination and using this to call the script.

Comment: Hm, when I try to run that script it says "module 'gui' not found", then gives some missing file errors for gui.dll, gui.lua, and init.lua. I was able to find gui.lua in the regular DF download and place it where it should be, although now it says "attempt to index local 'dscreen' (a nil value)", so I don't think that was quite right. Any ideas?

Comment: @SaintWacko: You need the **complete** current (v0.34.11 r2 as of this writing) version of DFHack to have the GUI module working, together with the right DwarfFortress version. If that problem persists, there might be an error in how DFHack interacts with Masterwork, but I doubt it. I could easily make this script work using your save (loaded by the default DF installation), after all.